# Swift 4.2 - Constraints Adding Extra Space

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to add a list of buttons in a stack view programmatically on swift. I have set a constraint on the stack view's width at 320 pixels and the buttons imageView contentMode=scaleAspectFit. All the button images are of different sizes.

When I add a button in the stack view it maintains the width and height of the buttons image, however the height constraint adds extra space where there shouldn't be any. I want the buttons to stack ontop of each other with no spacing

I've provided an example with imageViews on the storyboard.

Image already in stack view, constrains fit the image

[image]

Change the image and the height constraint adds extra space!

[image]

Any advice is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I am also having problems adding image views to a uibutton and maintaining a height, normally I set a fixed height for a uibutton and a imageview inside of it. The uibutton’s imageview height is equal to the height of the picture

Comment: What settings do you have on the stack view?  You probably want "fill proportionally"  Also, what is constraining the height of the stack view, if anything?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding height constraint with a simple formula.

1. currentWidth (Current width of image)
2. currentHeight (Current height of image

widthConstraint = 320

ratio = currentWidth / widthConstraint

heightConstraint = currentHeight / ratio